# matches.slice is not a function ng2-bootstrap typeahead

Tags: angular, rxjs, typeahead, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to use ng2-bootstrap Typeahead with REST backend.

## HTTP Response

```
[{
    "productDescription": "MAIL MKTG NIKLES HIGHLIGHT TUBE",
    "productNumber": "10667"
}, {
    "productDescription": "SIGHT GLASSES/VAC BREAKER BR 15MM BSP",
    "productNumber": "100436"
}, {
    "productDescription": "SIGHT GLASSES/VAC BREAKER BR 15MM BSP",
    "productNumber": "100438"
}]
```

## app.component.ts

```
import {TYPEAHEAD_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [TYPEAHEAD_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: './app/typeahead-demo.html',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, FreightService]
})
export class TypeaheadDemoComponent {
  public stateCtrl:FormControl = new FormControl();
  public myForm:FormGroup= new FormGroup({
    state: this.stateCtrl
  });

  public selected:string = '';
  public dataSource:Observable<any>;
  public asyncSelected:string = '';
  public typeaheadLoading:boolean = false;
  public typeaheadNoResults:boolean = false;

  public constructor(private freightService: FreightService) {
    this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer:any) => {
      observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
    }).mergeMap(() => this.getStatesAsObservable());
  }

  public getStatesAsObservable():Observable<any> {

    return Observable.of(
        this.freightService
            .getMatchingProduct(this.asyncSelected).map(error => console.log(error))
    );
  }
}
```

## freight.service.ts

I am using mocky.io to fake REST response.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class FreightService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    getMatchingProduct(productKeyword: string): Observable <string> {

        return this.http.get("http://www.mocky.io/v2/57b6988e0f0000b8020b7996")
            .map(this.extractData);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || { };
    }
}
```

## typeahead-demo.html

```
  <h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
  <pre class="card card-block card-header">Model: {{myForm.value.state | json}}</pre>
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input formControlName="state"
         [(ngModel)]="asyncSelected"
         [typeahead]="dataSource"
         (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)"
         (typeaheadNoResults)="changeTypeaheadNoResults($event)"
         (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
         [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="7"
         [typeaheadOptionField]="'productDescription'"
         placeholder="Locations loaded with timeout"
         class="form-control">
  </form>
```

I am really stuck with error "TypeError: matches.slice is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mapping all the result to undefined with this line: `.map(error => console.log(error))`. It will not catch errors, it will simply map all the values to the result of `console.log()` which will be undefined.

Also the result from `getMatchingProduct` should be an Observable so there is no need for `Observable.of`.

If you want to handle errors you can try the `.catch` method.

Comment: Adrian, Thanks for your reply. As you said, I changed getStatesAsObservable as below but still getting same error. Please help!!                 public getStatesAsObservable():Observable<any> {

    return this.freightService
            .getMatchingProduct(this.asyncSelected)
            .map((product) => this.products = product)
  }

Comment: You're doing the exact same thing but in a different way. No need to map the result to anything (certainly not to undefined), the stream will hold the results. The result of 'this.products = product' will be undefined, so you have the same error. You can look at [RxMarbles](http://rxmarbles.com/#map) to understand better the operators.

Comment: Also I suggest you read a bit about reactive programming. Something like '[The introduction to Reactive Programming you've been missing](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754)' will sure help.

Comment: Adrian, thanks for links. But any hint, how to make this work will be really appreciated. I have wasted lot of time on this :(

Comment: Adrian, I tried below, but still same error:   public constructor(private freightService: FreightService) {
    this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer:any) => {
       this.freightService.getMatchingProduct(this.asyncSelected)
       .subscribe((result: any) => {
         observer.next(result);
       })
    });
  }

Answer (score 1):

Below worked!!

## app.component.ts

```
  public constructor(private freightService: FreightService) {
    this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer:any) => {
       this.freightService.getMatchingProduct(this.asyncSelected)
       .subscribe((result: any) => {
         observer.next(result);
       })
    });
  }
```

## freight.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class FreightService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    getMatchingProduct(productKeyword: string): Observable <any> {

        return this.http.get("app/test").map(this.extractData);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || { };
    }
}
```